# How can I get comments to display under All posts

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, seq

Right now I have an application where I want to retrieve the comments from posts. I dont know what is the best way to go about this.

What i currently have only displays posts that has comments, but it doesnt show Multiple Comments only a single one.

```
<Grid item xl={8}>
    {this.props.posts.map((post, index) =>
      <PostBodyTemplate key={index} postId={post.id}  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e,post.id,post.userId,post.userIdName)} title={post.title} postBody={post.postBody} 
           giphyUrl = {post.giphyUrl} userWhoPosted={post.userIdName} commentBody={post.commentBody} userIdName={post.userIdName} />
       )} 
       {displayGifPicker ? (<AddGif selectedGif = {this.getGifState} />) : (<Button size="small" onClick={this.displayGifPicker} ><button>Add Gif</button></Button>)}
 </Grid>
```

The data is coming from The API that basically combines both the Posts And Comments table joining them by PostId, right now it only displays one comment and is only currently displaying Post that have comments.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
 sequelize.query( "SELECT comments.id, comments.postId, 
 comments.commentBody, comments.giphyurl, 
 comments.postPicture,comments.userId, comments.userIdto, 
 comments.userIdName, comments.userIdtoName, posts.postBody, posts.title, 
 posts.giphyUrl, posts.postPicture, posts.userId, posts.userIdName, 
 posts.userIdto, posts.userIdtoName FROM comments INNER JOIN posts ON 
 comments.postId = posts.id;")
.then(([results, metadata]) => {
res.json(results)
 })
})
```

Is there a better way I should go about this? The ideal solution to my problem would Grab all posts, display all post, if the post has comments then display all those comments also. The query I have only returns post that have comments, and mapping through them only shows one comment it doesnt display all..

To Get all comments currently i am just using a simple findAll, but this doesent display comments because the comments are in the comments table. Which is why i joined the tables in the previous query.

If it helps this is the component the props are sent to.

```
     export default function PostBodyTemplate(props) {
      const { onChange, onSubmit} = props
         const classes = useStyles();
        //  render() {
             return (
                <Grid item xs={12} xl={8} lg={8} style={fr}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardContent>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" style={fr}>
                      {props.userWhoPosted} Gave A VH5 To Julio {props.postId}
                  </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                      {props.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                      {props.postBody}
                    </Typography>
                    <img src={props.giphyUrl} style={giphyRes}/>
                </Paper>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                    <FavoriteIcon />
                    <div>Add Gif</div>
                  </IconButton>
                  <IconButton aria-label="share">
                    <EcoIcon />
                    <div>Add Photo</div>
                  </IconButton>
                  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <div className={classes.container}>
                    <TextField
                               onChange = {onChange}
                                name='commentBody'
                                id="standard-full-width"
                                label="Reply To Post"
                                style={{ margin: 8 }}
                                placeholder="Reply to Post"
                                fullWidth
                                margin="normal"
                                InputLabelProps={{
                                shrink: true,
                                }}
                        />
                      {/* <p><button>Send VH5</button></p> */}
                      {/* <Button onSubmit={onSubmit} size="small">Submit</Button> */}
                      <button onSubmit={onSubmit}>Submit VH5</button>
                    {/* <button onSubmit={onSubmit}>Submit Reply</button> */}

                    </div>
                  </form>
                  {/* <CommentInput onChange={onChange}/> */}
                  {/* <Button size="small">Submit</Button> */}
                </CardActions>
                <Paper className={classes.root} value={props.postId}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                    {props.commentBody}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                      {props.userIdName} replied to the post. 
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
              </Card>
              </Grid>
             )
        //  }
     }
```

Comment: To get posts that don't have comments you should be doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. BUT, when a post has more than one comment, you will receive multiple rows that duplicate the post columns, so you will need to reduce that somewhere (preferably on the server, but it could be done in JS too)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change your inner join to a `LEFT JOIN` to get all the posts whether or not they have comments. [More about joins](https://twitter.com/b0rk/status/1177611875535790087?s=09)